# Asset path generated in scss helper methods has duplicated asset prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I think this behaviour is a bug, but I'm also asking here. I already opened a bug report at sprockets-rails github repo.

I'm having problems with asset prefix. If I configure `Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = 'myprefix'`
in `config/initializers/assets.rb`, and then run:

`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clobber
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

all my precompiled assets get generated with correct path (`public/myprefix/asset_digest.png`). Finding assets from .erb file works correctly, the path is correctly generated and everything is shown correctly. The problem is that paths generated in `image-url()` and similar methods in .scss files get prefix two times.

So instead of `public/myprefix/background_digest.jpg` Rails is trying to find the image at the `public/myprefix/myprefix/background_digest.jpg`, but the image is correctly precompiled and saved to `public/myprefix` folder. One workaround is to simply copy all assets from `myprefix` to `myprefix/myprefix`, but it's a nasty way to deal with this. This happend only for assets referenced from .scss files.

To be sure it's not a problem with my configuration I tried to reproduce it on new application:

Ruby: 2.3.0
Rails: 4.2.6.
`rails new prefixtext -T
cd prefixtest
rails generate scaffold post title body:string`

configured:

- root route for posts#index
- one css rule in `application.scss`:
  `.background {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: image-url('my-background.jpg');
  }`
- div with .background class added to posts index view
- migrate db
- assets:clobber and assets:precompile
- start server
- all commands are prefixed with `RAILS_ENV=production`

I also tried with sprockets-rails version 2.3.2, and the same thing happens.

My machine is ArchLinux with rvm, buddy also tried on his machine (last Ubuntu also with rvm) and same thing happens on my server (CentOs 7 with rvm). 
Tested Ruby versions: 2.3.0, 2.1.2, 2.1.5.; tested Rails versions: 4.2.1, 4.2.6

Anyone has any idea what could be the case, or it really is a bug. How can I further test it?
Here is the bug report: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/363

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot one simple thing...the slash :)

Instead of having

```
Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = 'myprefix'
```

in config/initializers/assets.rb

you need to put

```
Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = '/myprefix'
```

And that's it...I did exactly what you did in your steps and it's working locally for me.

P.S. I just launched a new application on my production server and all was working good too.

Comment: The slash in the beginning of the prefix. It was left.